# Специфическая работа роутов в angular 4

Tags: angular2

Приветствую, нужно реализовать роуты таким образом:

```
site.ru/{название_компании}/login
site.ru/{название_компании}/home
и т.д.
```

Получается в каждой компании будут видеть свой `url` но функционал для всех один и тот же. Название компании выбирается после того, как пользователь верифицируется. Сейчас для всех компаний роуты выглядят так:

```
Routes = [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
      {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
      {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
];
```

Что-то мне кажется должно быть простое решение, но пока додумался только до

```
{path: ':project/home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
```

В этом случае необходимо во все ссылки дописывать название компании, коих уже не мало в проекте. Может есть какие-нибудь варианты решения?